# How to move the left side menu to the top of the page using a drop-down in Odoo 8?

Tags: css, menu, odoo-8, odoo, qweb

I tried to move the left side menu to the top of the page. But I need to create a drop down menu. How to achieve this?

[image]

Code :

```xml
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="oe_main_menu_placeholder">
    <ul id="oe_applications" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar-collapse collapse">
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
                Website
                <b class="caret" />
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li t-foreach="menu_data['children']" t-as="menu">
                    <t t-call="web.menu_link" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul id="menu_more" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <t t-call="web.menu_secondary" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It was like that in OpenERP 6.1, maybe it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.. do you have any link or something...

Comment: I found a couple of modules, check if my they help you. I wrote them in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the left menu with this module: [Web Menu Hide/Show](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_menu_hide_8.0/)

Or you can make what you want with this other module: [Advance Navigation For Menu](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/bista_advance_nav/)